# What do people exactly mean when they say "PhD supervisors guide their PhD students in their research"

Tags: phd, advisor

I am a statistics PhD student, and I just want to know what do people exactly mean when they say "PhD supervisors guide their PhD students in their research".

My supervisor is a Statistician. He has a master's and a PhD in statistics. His area of research is analysis of open-ended survey questions. Him and his past graduate students has worked on basic machine learning algorithms like KNN, SVM, etc to analyze open-ended survey responses. None of his previous research had involved applying a sophisticated deep learning based language models (e.g. Transformer, RNN ,LSTM) to analyze open-ended survey questions. He is in general not an expert in natural language processing (e.g. like those natural language processing professors from computer science department).

When I was starting my PhD program, I asked my supervisor about my general research direction, and my supervisor gave me a list of papers for me to read, and told me that this is where my research is heading. All of these papers were computer science papers on deep neural language models in natural language processing (which has no hint of analyzing survey open-ended responses). I got slightly confused and asked my supervisor that whether I am to apply these state-of-the-art natural language processing models to analyze open-ended survey responses. My supervisor told me that I won't be analyzing open-ended survey questions like he does.

So I read those papers, came up with research questions, and ran experiments and tried to make publications all of which were failures. I can't really discuss any technically of my work with my supervisor even at a broad level because he lacks the general knowledge about the field (e.g. he told me one day that he has never heard of the words like "syntax" and "semantics" before. These are all basic terminologies that any one in natural language processing community understands). I can't discuss technicality of my work with any of other faculty members / phd students in my department neither because the type of research I am doing mainly concerns with computer science and they don't do this type of research. It also took my supervisor quite sometime to understand that I need an access to good computing resource to be able to carry out a quality research. I'd really hate say this but these things tell me that he in general does not understand how natural language processing field works, and what natural language processing research entails.

So far the "guidance" I received from my supervisors over the past 5 semesters are:

- the list of papers that he gave me to read while I was starting out in the PhD program
- writing help with my publication drafts.

I would like to ask anyone who reads this posts if this is the right level of "guidance" that I am to expect as a PhD student, and whether I am entitled for more "guidance" than this from my supervisor. I personally feel that doing a research in natural languae processing / artificial intelligence all by myself in isolation is very risky and that I am not receiving adaquate supervision from my supervisor, but I might be wrong in that. Maybe I am bad as a researcher, or maybe I am just not good enough to make any publications. So I am just very confused about my situation and myself.

**Could my lack of performance as a researcher be due to the lack of supervision I am receiving? or is this level of superivison normal for PhD students?**

Thank you,

Comment: I have finished my PhD in biostatistics. In my case, it works like this "proposal -> correction". I had a real dataset with research questions. I used existing models or developed new models to answer them. My supervisor corrected me whenever necessary. I am curious why he lacks knowledge in that field but has PhD student working on that field?

Comment: He told me once that he purposefully discouraged me from pursuing analysis of open-ended survey questions because doing so takes learning many social science concepts which he figures that I wouldn't enjoy (he is wrong in this. I am willing to learn whatever the social science concepts that is necessary for me to learn in order to make successful publications or to graduate).

Comment: @TrungDung I do understand that as a PhD student, I am to do the literature search on my own and come up with my own research questions. Is it common for PhD student to expect to be somehow guided in their proposal stage as well, based on superviosr's knowledge? I understand that my supervisor can't be 100% familiar with the specific research topic that I've chosen, but I would imagine that if supervisor is familiar with the field in broad sense, then he or she would also approve/disapprove the proposal that students comes up with. am I wrong?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, but if you think your supervisor is unhelpful you should seek to get a new one.

Comment: I get that I somehow need to improve my question, but I don't know how to do it. Should I erase all my personal circumstances and just ask for the example of supervisions that PhD students are entitled to receive from their supervisor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with a supervisor who is not expert in my research field](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/159278).

Comment: *he has never heard of the words like "syntax" and "semantics" before* --- Interesting, as these are words one would also see in the kinds of very basic introductory logic courses that some (U.S.) universities allow to take the place of a general education required mathematics course(s) (usually satisfied by a college algebra course or and/or a math appreciation course), and the words are also "vocabulary words" that one would expect a strong high school student to have seen ("strong" in the sense of including anyone having the potential to later do any kind of post-undergraduate work).

Comment: Have you talked to other PhD students in your department/university? Is this hands-off supervision style common there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with a supervisor who is not expert in my research field](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/159278/working-with-a-supervisor-who-is-not-expert-in-my-research-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in mathematics, in the U.S.

For me, "advisors guide their students" means giving advice on reasonable projects, to say the least. And advice on what may work, or fail. And weekly feedback on what has happened so far.

Although I do encourage my students to think about whatever comes into their minds, "good (naive) ideas" is/are not the same thing as "good PhD project". So we (collectively) negotiate a middle ground.

I do understand that there are some models of "advisor" in which the "advisor" does essentially nothing, apart from eventually signing... I do not understand this. And I do not *believe* anyone who claims that PhD students are somehow supposed to do something, unaided, which more serious people have cared enough to try to understand/resolve, but have failed.

Comment: Hi Professor, thank you very much for your reply. in my situation, would it be appropriate for me to ask my supervisor for changing my research direction from natural language processing to analysis of open-ended survey questions? My supervisor told me that he is taking on a new project of analyzing the survey open-ended responses with deep learning models, and I think that if I ask him this question, he will probably get me work on this new project. My fear is that this venture is not likely to be successful.

Comment: Applying deep neural network for analysis requires a big text data, and in general survey texts does not fit into this "big data" category. I have talked to a group of people who has worked on applying deep neural networks to analyze survey analysis, and they all tell me the same thing that doing so is meaningless unless the survey data is large....which isn't the case for my supervisor's data.